# Undersubscribed ESXI host shows 100% CPU

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, performance-monitoring

I guess the question is more theoretical one. We have ESXI host with 48 Logical Cores (HT enabled, 24 real cores). We run 4 machines each provisioned with 8 vCpu. Each machine operates on 75% CPU on according to guest (top) and host (VSphere monitor) metrics.

Important detail - the machines are relatively network heavy receiving 700Mb/s of application traffic each.

ESXI is vanilla using regular switch, and VM do not use any special resource management configuration (shares, affinity, etc)

However it appears that ESXI as host is operating at 100% level. How come? All machines occupy only 32 out of 48 logical CPU and even with 100% occupancy plus add several vCPus (?) for traffic handling on ESXI part, how do we theoretically get to 100% CPU host usage?

Comment: 4 VMs x 8vCPUs x 75% = 24 Cores at 100% - why would you think the host is undersubscribed?

Comment: The host has 48 logical cpus the machines can use at most 32 (8*4) = which leaves 16 logical CPU unused

Comment: `how do we theoretically get to 100% CPU host usage?` add a fifth virtual with the same or similar workload. Quick maffs.

Answer (score 3):

4 VMs * 8vCPUs * 75% load = 2400% = 24 cores at 100% load

Your host isn't undersubscribed, it's fully loaded.

SMT aka Intel Hyperthreading doesn't add actual cores, there's just an additional execution thread on each pCore to utilize idle function units. It doesn't magically double the number of physical cores.

Ie. when one thread utilizes its logical core by 100%, both SMT cores on that physical core are at 100%. Only when the first thread is waiting for some resource that the second thread doesn't need, does the latter actually run.

Comment: Not sure I get the math here. You take VM logical CPU which is mapped from host scheduler point of view to host thread not to full core (I may be wrong here), and compare it to number of host full cores. Can you clarify.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at it this way: loading one logical core simultaneously loads its twin on the same physical core.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, examine the network configurations of the VMs. Throttle or optimize the network traffic to reduce the load on the ESXi host. This can be achieved by implementing bandwidth restrictions or adjusting network settings to prioritize critical data.

Secondly, assess the current hardware configuration of the ESXi host. If there is room for expansion, consider adding more physical cores. This will provide the host with additional processing power to handle the demands of the network traffic more efficiently.

Finally, evaluate the version of ESXi in use. Upgrading to a newer version can often bring performance improvements and enhanced capabilities, specifically in managing network-intensive workloads.